# Removing a specific div from HTML string

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have an HTML string from which I want to strip a specific div and all of its content based on some condition my div has a specific class and it contains some other nested divs in there. I have tried to use regex but the problem is that it picks up the first `</div>` and ignores the following content.

```
string html = "<div class=\"card-set--six manual-cardset\"><div>test string</div></div>";
html = new Regex("<div class=\"card-set--six manual-cardset\">.*?</div>").Replace(html, string.Empty);
```

In my case, it should remove all the content and I should get an empty string. But this regex is returning me `</div>`.

Comment: Dont use regex, use a library that is meant for this like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: [Using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Comment: @maccettura I definitely had that in mind but the problem is this is actually used in a 3rd party .NET based CMS and using 3rd party extensions and dll`s in there is not very straightforward so I went on to try some Regex but as 
@SaniSinghHuttunen suggested Regex might not do the work here.

Comment: do u want to replace the entire div by nothing? or only "test string" ?

Comment: @Aamir I guess I am not understanding why you cannot use HtmlAgilityPack.  I use it often in CMS development work.  You are doing the work above in C# no?  So why is there any restriction on what packages you can use from Nuget?  HtmlAgilityPack is free...

Comment: @AlanDeep the Idea is to replace the whole div with class "card-set--six manual-cardset" with nothing.

Comment: try to remove the question mark, do not believe the downvoters

Comment: @AlanDeep Thanks, that actually fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm glad bro! @Aamir

Answer (score -2):

Remove the question mark after **.*?**

Comment: I wonder why are you down-voting when this actually fixed @Aamir's problem